# TypeError: this.selectedNodes.value is not iterable

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

So I am working with v-network-graphs to create graphs in the front end using Vue.
I have defined my data as

```
data(){
    return{
      test: test_data,
      nodes:{},
      edges:{},
      nextNodeIndex: Number,
      selectedNodes: ref<string[]>([]),
      selectedEdges: ref<string[]>([]) 
    }
  }
```

and my methods are defined as

```
methods: {
    g(){  
      this.nodes = reactive(this.test.nodes)
      this.edges = reactive({ ...this.test.edges })
      console.log(this.nodes)
      console.log(this.edges)

      this.nextNodeIndex = ref(Object.keys(this.nodes).length + 1)     
    },
    addNode() {
      const nodeId = this.nextNodeIndex.value 
      this.nodes[nodeId] = {
        name: String(nodeId),
        size: 16,
        color: "blue",
        label: true
      } 
      this.nextNodeIndex.value++ 
      console.log(this.nextNodeIndex)
    },
    removeNode() {
      for (const nodeId of this.selectedNodes.value) {
        delete this.nodes[nodeId] //Delete the selected node, by their ID
      }
    },
```

Now when I try to remove a node I am getting the error `this.selectedNodes.value is not iterable` , how should I define selectedNodes then?

https://dash14.github.io/v-network-graph/examples/operation.html#add-remove-network-elements

The above link has an example on how to write remove edge function using the library. I am doing the same, but I want to write the function inside a method as I am working in a Vue project.
I am new to Javascript and Vue so any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is using [OptionsAPI](https://vuejs.org/api/options-state.html) `data` function to create state which is reactive and the guide that you are referring to is using a [Script setup](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html) that requires the use of `ref()` function to create reactive variables.

Because `data` returns object state that is already reactive, the use of `ref` within it is redundant and its properties will still be accessible via the `.` notation without the use of `value`.

So in your example, you should change the following:

```
for (const nodeId of this.selectedNodes.value) {
```

to

```
for (const nodeId of this.selectedNodes) {
```

And you can additionally replace the following two properties in `data`:

```
selectedNodes: ref<string[]>([]),
selectedEdges: ref<string[]>([])
```

to

```
selectedNodes: [],
selectedEdges: []
```

Hope this helps you!